# jQuery not working out of VScode, but does out of the Internet.. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, visual-studio-code, vs-web-site-project

I am learning to build websites and at the moment I am coding in visual-studio code insiders, with most jQuery plugins installed.

When I open this url :

" http://www.completewebdevelopercourse.com/content/4-jquery/4.3.html "

which has identical source code as the code below,
I get two different results.

one, In which the java-script is working (this is the page from the link), and in the other(stored in a local folder and opened inside VScode), it is not.

I have consulted the VS-code website and forums. No luck and my problem is not mentioned at all. Only that there does not seem to be a good plugin for jQuery but snippet-packages, which I have installed.

And normal google-ling gives me all the same results in which people are asking for jQuery plugins as mentioned above

How can this be? And how do I fix it?

[code]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<head>
    
    <title>jQuery</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <style type="text/css">
    
        #circle {
            
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            border-radius: 50%;
            background-color: green;
            margin: 10px;
            
        }
        
        .square {
            
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            background-color: red;
            margin: 10px;
            
        }
    
    
    </style>
    
</head>

<body>
    
   <div id="circle"></div>
    
    <div class="square"></div>
    
    <div class="square"></div>
    
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        
        $("div").click(function() {
            
            alert("a div was clicked!");
            
        });
        
        
        
        
        
        
    
        
    
    </script>
    
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you downloaded the jquery.min.js file (you should place it in the same folder of the html page), otherwise it would go 404.

Comment: Thanks, but 404 is not the problem? But in case, just download and paste it inside the folder?